# How to exclude array, when sub array contain specific value

Tags: php, arrays

I have array code like this below

```
Array
(
    [52] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 52
            [post_author] => 1
        )

    [53] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 53
            [post_author] => 2
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 10
            [post_author] => 2
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 9
            [post_author] => 1
        )

)
```

how to exclude the result who contain [post_author] => 2 so the result will be like this (been search on google but dont know what is the right keyword to solve this problem, noobs here :D )

```
Array
(
    [52] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 52
            [post_author] => 1
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 9
            [post_author] => 1
        )

)
```

thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php. Have a look at this.

Comment: Either use a simple loop and filter the array or you can use `array_filter()` for your case.

Comment: got it, figure out with loop, thx @Rizier123 for the link above :)